# How to get the outerHTML of the current selected element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the htmls:

```
<div id="t">
   <a class="xx">xx</a>
   <a class="yy">yy</a>
   <a class="zz">zz</a>
</div>
```

Now how about if I want to get the links whose class is `xx` or `zz`, that's to say I want to get this:

```
   <a class="xx">xx</a>
   <a class="zz">zz</a>
```

I tried this:

```
$("#t a").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(".xx,.yy"){
    //here how to get the out the HTML of the current a element?
  }
});
```

Any alternatives?

I noted that there are two answers, but it seems that they misunderstand me.

```
$("#t a").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(".xx,.yy"){
    //here I want to get the full HTML of the `a` element
    // That's to say, I want to get `<a class="xx">xx</a>`

     // I can not use $(this).html() or $(this).text() which will only return the `xx`.
  }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419749/get-selected-elements-outer-html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#t a.xx,#t a.yy").each(function(){
    $('<div>').append($(this).clone()).html();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

The other answers are incorrect. Here is exactly how you'd get it.

```
$('a.xx,a.yy').each(function(index, currentLink){
   var z = currentLink.outerHTML;   //z will be <
});
```

Another solution, using jQuery to get the anchor HTML:

```
$('a.xx,a.yy').each(function(index, currentLink){
   alert($(currentLink.outerHTML).wrap('<p/>').parent().html());
});
```

Here's the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wabjw/

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I updated my answer to include a jQuery solution which should work since it looks like you are using jQuery already.

Answer (score 1):

```
var html = '';
$('#t a.xx, #t a.zz').each(function(){
  html += $(this).wrap('<p/>').parent().html();
  $(this).unwrap();
});
```

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rwGsR/9/

Answer (score 1):

Is this correct?

JS:

```
$("#t a").each(function(){
  if($(this).is(".xx,.yy")){
    console.log(this.outerHTML);
  }
});
```

It return: `"<a class=\"xx\">xx</a>"` & `"<a class=\"yy\">yy</a>"` in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can try .find()

```
$("#t").find('.xx,.yy')
```